# Error when trying to implement 2 methods in another method - java

Tags: java, inheritance, methods

I have 2 methods isArithmetric and isRelational, both of these methods are used to see if e belongs to a certain instance of a class (eg. if e is a type like 2 + 3 then its in isArithmetric and is an instanceof Additiona, and if e is like 3 > 2 then its in isRelational and is an instanceof GreaterThan). I need to implement the isTypeCorrect method which I know uses the two methods mentioned above to see if when used, returns true if e is either one of the two methods above, and false otherwise. The thing is, I don't know how to implement isTypeCorrect, I tried to call the method from isTypeCorrect and used an if statement but it would not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
private boolean isArithmetic(Expression e) {
    return 
            e instanceof Addition 
        ||  e instanceof Subtraction
        ||  e instanceof Multiplication;
}

/**
 * sub-routine that can be used to check if this is type correct
 * true if e is one of the three classes, or their subclasses (if any)
 */
private boolean isRelation(Expression e) {
    return 
            e instanceof Equal 
        ||  e instanceof GreaterThan
        ||  e instanceof LessThan;
}

/**
 * If this collector is AddAll or TimesAll, then all stored expressions must be integer expressions
 * (i.e., Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication).
 * If this collection is ConjoinAll or DisjoinAll, then all stored expressions must be boolean expressions
 * (i.e., GreaterThan, LessThan, Equal)
 * @return whether it is possible to evaluate the stored collection of expressions.   
 */
boolean isTypeCorrect() {

}
```

Comment: Explain *"my implementation does not work"*.  And give examples of the types you are testing.

Comment: How are you referencing this and AddAll and TimesAll ? Please be more descriptive about what is an error you are facing.

Comment: Can you provide a SSCE (http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: You edited your question and removed the code in the `isTypeCorrect` method.  How does that provide any useful information to answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code.

```
boolean isTypeCorrect() {
    boolean result = false;
    AddAll a = new AddAll();
    TimesAll t = new TimesAll();
    if (this.isArithmetic(a) || this.isRelation(t)) {
        result = true;
    }

    return result;
}
```

`a` and `t` are new instances of `AddAll` and `TimesAll` respectively with no changeable arguments to a constructor.  How could they ever be anything different each time you invoke this method.  In fact, they are going to be `local` values and go out of scope when you exit the method.  I can't tell what is going on but it looks like a design flaw.